# ModuleNotFoundError - Airflow cannot find a packaged module

Tags: python, airflow, sys

Airflow beginner here.  I recently installed Airflow and am in the process of creating a DAG.  My issue is that when I run Airflow, I get the error that it cannot find my package of "etl_package".  This is odd b/c this package is in the same directory (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages)
as the airflow packages used in my code.  I've verified this is on my PYTHONPATH.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from etl_package.data_collect.dropbox_download_file import DownloadMoveFiles as dlm

with DAG("mydag", start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1),
         schedule_interval="@daily", catchup=False) as dag:


    collect_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="dbx_collection",
        python_callable=dlm.collect_move
    )
```

I think the error might be the location of my DAGS folder.  It currently resides on my desktop and thus is not in the root folder of where the rest of my python code is.  However, if this is the issue, then I'm confused as to why Airflow can recognize the imported airflow modules.  Thank you and appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked if airflow was referenced through your IDE and not from the project folder? Last time I had a project with a lot of externals I put everything from the root of my project folder. If you do not, then you need to specify the path which would only work locally (if you care)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I believe that Airflow was referenced from my IDE (i used Pycharm to install all of the airflow packages)  The project folder (which has my dags) only has a docker-compose yaml file and folders for the plugins, dags, and logs.   How would I go about specifying the path as I am only working locally for now.

Comment: Will it be possible to describe your airflow env. Is it running inside a docker container?

Comment: Yes, it is running inside a docker container.  I installed it via the a docker_compose.yaml script (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml).  This .yaml file is within a folder on my desktop that is outside of the root folder my pycharm works in.

Comment: @Danielme, I put everything in the root of my project folder and this worked.  It took me a while to figure out how Docker works and this solution was a working one.  Thank you

Comment: @thehungrypanda121 Glad to hear. Every time I start a new project there always seems to be problems with assemblies/config. You are not alone lol